# Determine if a Word document or Excel spreadsheet has a macro included

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

When reading the binary of a Word or Excel document into memory, is it possible to inspect the data to determine if a macro is built into it?

Answer (score 1):

If you set the security level for macros Excel (and I expect word) will ask you if you want to run a macro only if there are macros.

Comment: The situation we have is that we are reading the binary of the word/excel doc and would like to know within the program we wrote if the binary has a macro. Since this is happening server side, we'd like to capture the fact that a macro is included and avoid any UI pop-up.